# DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record

Tags: unit-test

```
Account parentAccount = TestUtils.createAccountWithRecordType(Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Parent Account').getRecordTypeId(),false);
        parentAccount.City__c = 'Delhi';
        insert parentAccount;

Account childAccount = TestUtils.createAccountWithRecordType(Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Account').getRecordTypeId(),false);
        childAccount.ParentId = parentAccount.id;
        childAccount.City__c = 'Jaipur';
        **insert childAccount;** // Here Error is Comming
```

Comment: Do you have any field on Account that is marked as Unique ?

Comment: Is it only your code? Or are you adding twice childs or Parent, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context that error suggests that both the parentAccount and the childAccount share the same value for some unique identifier. I wonder if you have an external ID configured and this is getting set the same in both cases?

Comment: Thank you, Yes it is working now